# SQL COUNT And SUM

Tags: sql, count, sum, radix, libreoffice

I have a table having this
table done_by

```
Var_ID| Var_name| Q1_by  |Q2_by|Q3_by|Q4_by
1     |    abc  |   me   | me  |me   |you
2     |    cba  |   me   | me  |you  |you
3     |    abd  |   me   | you |you  |me
```

the result i want to get is get all the total of all the 
me and you value
me=7
you=5

have done count, but what i cant get is count for all the 'me' for each column

Comment: What version of SQL are you using ? Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle or another database engine ?

Comment: It's usually a sign of a broken data model when you want to compute/compare values in multiple columns - it's usually a sign that there should be a single column and more rows (and that `Q1` - `Q4` should also be appearing as *data* in a separate column, rather than being embedded as metadata in column names)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with conditional aggregation like:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Q1_by = 'me' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN Q2_by = 'me' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN Q3_by = 'me' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN Q4_by = 'me' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS me ,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Q1_by = 'you' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + 
           CASE WHEN Q2_by = 'you' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN Q3_by = 'you' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
           CASE WHEN Q4_by = 'you' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS you
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgi Nakeuri the conditional aggregation worked and gave me results that i needed, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use individual counts per quarter and add them

```
SELECT (
(SELECT Count(Q1_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q1_by = 'me')+
(SELECT Count(Q2_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q2_by = 'me')+
(SELECT Count(Q3_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q3_by = 'me')+
(SELECT Count(Q4_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q4_by = 'me')) AS MeCount,
(
(SELECT Count(Q1_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q1_by = 'you')+
(SELECT Count(Q2_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q2_by = 'you')+
(SELECT Count(Q3_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q3_by = 'you')+
(SELECT Count(Q4_by) FROM done_by WHERE Q4_by = 'you')) AS YouCount
FROM done_by
```

IDEONE link: https://ideone.com/ZAuS5O

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregates using "Sum" instead of "Count" is way to go, you can extend it by using dynamic sql, if you don't know the distinct values -

```
--Dynamic SQL Extension to count sum of all distinct values
--Extract out distinct values in temporary table
SELECT DISTINCT by_val=val INTO #by_tbl FROM (SELECT  val=Q1_by
FROM #TableName
UNION ALL 
SELECT  val=Q2_by
FROM #TableName
UNION ALL 
SELECT val=Q3_by
FROM #TableName
UNION ALL 
SELECT val=Q4_by
FROM #TableName) A


--Create a SQL String 
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)

SELECT @sql = ISNULL(@sql+',', 'SELECT ') + '['+by_val+']=SUM(CASE WHEN Q1_by='''+by_val+''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                + CASE WHEN Q2_by='''+by_val+''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                + CASE WHEN Q3_by='''+by_val+''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                + CASE WHEN Q4_by='''+by_val+''' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '

FROM #by_tbl

SET @sql = @sql + ' FROM #TableName'

EXEC(@SQL)


DROP TABLE #TableName
DROP TABLE #by_tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @byMe INT = 0;

SELECT @byMe = @byMe + COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablName
WHERE Q1_by = 'me';

SELECT @byMe = @byMe + COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablName
WHERE Q2_by = 'me';

SELECT @byMe = @byMe + COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablName
WHERE Q3_by = 'me';

SELECT @byMe = @byMe + COUNT(*) FROM dbo.tablName
WHERE Q4_by = 'me';

SET @byMe = @byMe * 7;
```